# How to achieve HSPD-12 (and CAC) using openam

Tags: openam, opendj

Which document I need to refer to implement HSPD-12 (and CAC) with OpenAM 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAC cards utilise X.509 certificates, so you will need to use an X.509 Authentication Module for those.

[Here is the official documentation for enabling X.509 Authentication](https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/13/admin-guide#cert-module-conf-hints), and [here's a wiki entry for it too](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/X.509+Authentication%3A+Including+SmartCards).